# Disallow xml robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

[Google webmaster FAQs](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) suggest that this will exclude all xml files from search:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*.xml$
```

Is this legal for other bots as well?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.xml$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is valid.  Whether other bots actually understand and obey is completely up to them, though!